# Compile different code for same project - Swift framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have several apps that using the same core framework, Since each app have some small differences i'm searching for the best way to build the framework with relevant code and parameters.
The best solution (that is not so good) that i found is:

1. For different code compilation - using targets that include different classes
2. For different configuration using different Swift flags for each configuration (e.g. debug, release...)

The problems are:

1. I'm using several targets and each target duplicate the project configuration and i need to maintain all. this approach can lead to some bugs if i change configuration in one target but forget to change it on other target.
2. For debug/release & stagingA/stagingB/production I'm creating specific configurations instead combining them (This solution is problematic since for each staging i need to duplicate it for release and debug):

   1. release production
   2. debug production
   3. release stagingA
   4. debug stagingA
   5. release stagingB
   6. debug stagingB

Apps struct is:

- App A  include CoreFramework with code adjustments for A
- App B  include CoreFramework with code adjustments for B

Each app have debug, release, production... configuration. This configurations affect the framework (these configuration run also on the framework)

==> I'm looking for other/better way to configure my apps project's

Answer (score 2):

Don't make "code adjustments" in the framework based on which client is calling it.

Construct your framework as if it were something provided as a binary release by an external supplier.  Any behaviour that may be variable can then only be controlled by run-time configuration through a public API.

Comment: I need the "code adjustments"  for each app for example there is public API that i don't want to expose for specific apps while other need it.

Comment: Sorry to hear that...it sounds like your current problem is just a natural result of a bad design.